# QToolButtons Not-Flat Button Style

Tags: qt4, qtoolbar, qaction

I am using Qt Widgets version 4.8.  I am placing QAction objects into a QToolBar.  I am displaying text only, no icons.  The text appears flat with no outline, until one hovers over the text, and then the text appears as a button.  I would prefer to have that button look all the time, and not just on hover.

I recognize that the flat look seems standard everywhere, but it is always used with icons.
I also recognize that the background shading of the QToolBar makes it apparent that it is a toolbar and therefore contains actions.  However, to everyone that I have shown the application to, it is not apparent to them that there are actions there at all, and I have had management ask me to make it look like a button all the time.

I have Qt configured to use the CleanLooks style.  Unfortunately, this does not appear to be defined by a style sheet that I can modify.  If I try to set a style for a QToolButton, this style erases the original style, instead of just updating a single item.  I would need to know all the original values to do this properly.

Any answers or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `QAction * QToolBar::addWidget ( QWidget * widget )` method to add an *actual* button on your toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`QToolBar::widgetForAction`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbar.html#widgetForAction). For example:

```
auto toolButton =
    static_cast<QToolButton *>(toolBar->widgetForAction(action));

toolButton->setAutoRaise(false);
```

From my own answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31972514/2507567